# Firebase realtime how to work listen method?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
"abc": {
  "a": "aaaa",
  "b": "bbbb",
  "c": "cccc",
  "d": "dddd",
},
```

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("abc").onValue.listen((event){ });
```

Let's imagine that there is such an output that I listen to live from firebase realtime. When there is a change in the value of `a`, does it cost as much as the size of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` or the size of the changed data?

I want to listen to a part with thousands of users. Will we write thousands of users in mb in every user movement?

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

**If** the SDK already has a local version of the data at `abc`  (either in its disk-based cache or because the listener is active already), it requests only the delta from that data from the server.

It does this by calculating the hash of the individual branches of the local data, and the server then compares that to the hashes of the current branches and only returns the branches that are modified. In practice it is seldom the minimal set of changed data, but it can be substantially smaller than the full data under `abc`.

Note that you won't notice this behavior on the API level, as the SDK always merges the delta with its local data and raises a complete snapshot.

Comment: that is, if we consider that there are data from a to z under the node and when the d data changes, it returns all of them, but do you mean it writes as much as the d data changes?

Comment: The SDK always raises a complete snapshot. I added an explanaiton of that to my answer. If you'd like to see what actually gets sent under the hood, you can [enable debug logging](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/FirebaseDatabase/setLoggingEnabled.html) and check the output.

Comment: FirebaseDatabase.instance.setLoggingEnabled(true);
  i'm trying this but i can't see it in my logs do you have any idea